# Broadcast dot product in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow, I have the following problem.

I have a tensor **m** of shape [batch_size, dim_a, dim_b] and a matrix **u** of shape [batch_size, dim_b].

```
M = tf.constant(shape=[batch_size, sequence_size, embed_dim])
U = tf.constant(shape=[batch_size, embed_dim])
```

What I what to achieve is the dot product of  [i, dim_a, dim_b] x [i, dim_b] for each index of my batch.

```
P[i] = tf.matmul(M[i, :, :], tf.expand_dims(U[i, :], 1)) for each i.
```

Basically, broadacast the dot product over the batch axis. Is this possible and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Since every vector is a matrix with 1 column, you could reshape U. Tensorflow used to have `batch_matmul` before version 1.0, which has been merged with `matmul` now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with tf.einsum():

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 2
sequence_size = 3
embed_dim = 4

M = tf.constant(range(batch_size * sequence_size * embed_dim), shape=[batch_size, sequence_size, embed_dim])
U = tf.constant(range(batch_size, embed_dim), shape=[batch_size, embed_dim])

prod = tf.einsum('bse,be->bs', M, U)

with tf.Session():
  print "M"
  print M.eval()
  print
  print "U"
  print U.eval()
  print
  print "einsum result"
  print prod.eval()
  print

  print "numpy, example 0"
  print np.matmul(M.eval()[0], U.eval()[0])
  print
  print "numpy, example 1"
  print np.matmul(M.eval()[1], U.eval()[1])
```

Output:

```
M
[[[ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6  7]
  [ 8  9 10 11]]

 [[12 13 14 15]
  [16 17 18 19]
  [20 21 22 23]]]

U
[[2 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3]]

einsum result
[[ 18  62 106]
 [162 210 258]]

numpy, example 0
[ 18  62 106]

numpy, example 1
[162 210 258]
```